# Rails form_for accepts only numeric values with the same decimal fractions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a variable in my model that accepts float values. When creating an object everything works fine. The problem arises when I'm trying to edit the value. I validate it like this:

```
validates :amount, presence: true

validates_numericality_of :amount, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0
```

When I'm trying to edit an object it only accepts the values that have the same value after a decimal point. For example if my initial value was 2.1 it would accept 3.1 or 4.1 but not 2.0 or 2.5. I think the problem is in validation, but here's also my update method:

```
def update

  @entry = Entry.find(entry_params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|

    if @entry.update_amount(entry_params[:amount])

      @entry.save

      format.html { redirect_to diary_url(:curr_day => entry_params[:day])}#, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @entry }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and update_amount:

```
def update_amount(amount)
  self.amount = amount
end
```

Anyone can advice me what to do?

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Show your error's messages. Too try `self.amount = amount.to_f`

Comment: @AlexKojin I added a screenshot. to_f didn't work unfortunately

Comment: This message came from a server? Do you have any other validations? Open  `rails console` and try `Entry.first.update_amount(4.4)`

Comment: Nevermind, added ":step => 0.1" and it works now. weird